# How to render a view when a (Mailjet) cURL request is finnished?

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, mailjet, cakephp-2.x

I'm stuck on this problem and can't figure out how to solve it.

I'm using CakePhp 2.x, as a framework, and Mailjet to send mails, and get their status. (Mailjet is a French competitor of Mailchimp). 
I want to display in my index all the campaigns sent through Mailjet.

In my EmailController :

```
public function index() {

    $clubCampaigns = $this->getMJAllCampaigns('emailofthe@club.com');

    $viewCampaigns = array();

    foreach ($clubCampaigns as $key => $Campaign) {
            $viewCampaigns[$key]['Subject'] = $Campaign->Subject;
            $viewCampaigns[$key]['Campaign'] = $this->getMJCampaign($Campaign->ID);
            $viewCampaigns[$key]['Messages'] = $this->getMJMessageSentStatistics($Campaign->ID);
        }
    $this->set('viewCampaigns', $viewCampaigns);

    return $this->render();
}
```

I get my email campaign with this function.

```
protected function getMJAllCampaigns($senderID = null, $fromTS = null, $toTS = null ) {

    /* @render  none  */
    $this->autoRender = false;

    if($senderID == null || $senderID == ''){
        throw new Exception('$SenderID is NULL : Cannot request Mailjet API');
        return false;
    }

    if($toTS == null){
        $toTS       =   new DateTime();
    }

    if($fromTS == null){
        $fromTS     =   new DateTime();
        $fromTS->sub(new DateInterval("P1W"));
    }

    /* Create Mailjet Object */
    $Mailjet    =   new Mailjet();

    $params = array (
        'Limit'     =>  1000,
        'FromID'    =>  $SenderID,
        'From'      =>  $SenderID,
        'FromTS'    =>  $fromTS->format(DATE_RFC3339),  //Format T RFC 3339 DateTime
        'ToTS'      =>  $toTS->format(DATE_RFC3339)     //Format T RFC 3339 DateTime
    );


    $MJCampaign = $Mailjet->campaign($params);

    /* Parsing cURL response */
    $countCampaign  =   $MJCampaign->Count;
    $campaigns      =   $MJCampaign->Data;

    if($countCampaign == 0 || $campaigns == null){
        //throw new Exception('No campaign found - Break');
        $campaigns = false;
    }

    return $campaigns;
}
```

I'm using a Mailjet Object, given by the [Mailjet API](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-simple). This API is a bench of PHP functions creating cURL resquest.

I know this code is, in state, functional.

Because when I `var_dump($clubCampaigns); die;`, it renders the expected array.

But when I try to launch it "naturally", the view is not rendered, loading the time set as `max_execution_time` in my `php.ini`...

I think that CakePhp is trying to execute the `foreach` and render the view before the `$this->getMJAllCampaigns` is complete.

So my question is :

How can I tell my foreach to start only when my `$this->getMJAllCampaigns()` is completely done ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this to get every campaigns from a specific sender:

```
$result = $mj->campaign([
    'FromEmail' => 'sender email'
]);

var_dump($result);
```

See this documentation: http://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/campaign/

Comment: I did change the manner to access MJ. My methods were way to heavy...
Thank you very much @guillaume